# Cryptography. Get worst result of enncryption

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, key

In the code below, foo () forms the key (the leftmost element of the generated sequence is taken). This key is then used to encrypt the message using ^. That is, every character in a word must be a ^ with a key. For this I use the ENCODE function. Outputs only the result ^ with the key and the first character (calculated correctly). For some reason, the rest does not touch.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

std::vector<char> foo(std::vector<char>& key2) {
    uint32_t state = 0b1111111111111111111111111111111;
    uint32_t start_state2{ state };
    uint32_t period {0};
    uint32_t bit2 {0};
    do {
        bit2 = ((state >> 31) ^ (state >> 30) ^ (state >> 29) ^ (state >> 25) ^ state);
        //bit2 = key2[period];
        (key2[period]) = (bit2);
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(key2[period]) << " ";
        state = (state >> 1) | (bit2 << 31);

        std::cout << std::bitset<32>(state) << std::endl;
        period++;

    } while ((period != 15) && (start_state2 != state));

    std::cout << "Period: " << period << std::endl;
    return key2;
}

const int SIZE{8};
void ENCODE(std::string data, std::vector<char>& key2) {
    std::vector<std::bitset<SIZE>> vec_bitset_data;

        for(unsigned i=0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
            std::bitset<SIZE> d(data[i]);
            std::bitset<SIZE> k(key2[i]);

            std::bitset<SIZE> encoded = d^k;
           std::cout << encoded << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << " ";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<char> key2(32);


    foo(key2);

    std::string data;
    data = "Hello";

    std::cout << "\nData string: " << data << '\n';
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        std::bitset<8> d(data[i]);
        std::cout << d << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Key: ";
    for(unsigned i=0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << std::bitset<8>(key2[i]) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    ENCODE(data, key2);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Data string: Hello
01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111
Key: 11000010 11100001 10110111 10011100 11001110
10001010 10000100 11011011 11110000 10100001
```

Comment: what do you expect the output to be? What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: You should see result 01001000 ^ 01100100 ```(H (in ascii) ^ 01100100)```. It is 00101100 (true). Then 01100101 ^ 01100100 ```(e (in ascii) ^ 01100100)```. But it is 00000001. Not true. Then l ^ 01100100, o ^ 01100100. As you see I have only one value in result.

Comment: `key2` is an uninitialized pointer.  Dereferencing it causes the behavior of your program to be undefined.  Perhaps you want to use `std::vector<char>` and `push_back` into it in `foo`?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69560362/edit) clarifications into your question rather than adding them as comments

Comment: @MilesBudnek I try it now. But when I use ```std::bitset<1>(key)``` for ```0``` I have ```0```. When I do ```std::bitset<8>(key)``` for ```0``` I have ```11000010```. Edited code is above.

Comment: Yes?  I'm not sure why you find that surprising.  The least-significant bit of `11000010` is `0`.  A `std::bitset<1>` holds one bit.  Your program's behavior is still undefined though, for multiple reasons (writing out of the bounds of `key2` in `foo` as well as failing to return any value from your non-`void` functions).

Comment: So is It true? For example I have ```std::bitset<8>(key)``` for ```0``` like ```10011100```. Above I add code with fixed any warnings. But I don't understand how to fix ```riting out of the bounds of key2 in foo```